# JavaScript / HTML5 audio: play mp3 file loaded by user via file selector in Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-audio

I am trying to create a site where user can select a local audio file from their PC or tablet and (without uploading the file to the server) play that file using HTML5 audio tag (user is supposed to click the button to play it, autoplay feature is not needed). I am not able to achieve this in Android version of Chrome despite the fact that this browser should support everything that is needed. In desktop version of Chrome it works.

I have tried different methods how to load that file:

1. via JavaScript FileReader - you can fiddle with it here:  http://liveweave.com/2kOWoz

   ```
   function handleFileSelect(evt) {
       var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
       playFile(files[0]);
   }

   function playFile(file) {
       var freader = new FileReader();

       freader.onload = function(e) {
           player.src = e.target.result;
       };

       freader.readAsDataURL(file);
   }

   player = document.getElementById('player');
   document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
   document.getElementById('play').onclick = function(){ player.play(); };
   ```
2. via URL.createObjectURL - edit here: http://liveweave.com/4y84XV
   The second one is very similar to the first one - only playFile function is like this:

   ```
   function playFile(file) {
       player.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   }
   ```

What is wrong with those examples? Is there any other way how to achieve the expected result? I would appreciate any hints or ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I think I can help.  Would you mind creating a jsFiddle or posting your code for what you have working on the desktop?  Then we can go from there...

Comment: @tennisgent thank you - there is a code to play with - those two links go to liveweave.com, which is something like jsFiddle (I just like it more). I should probably make it clearer.

Comment: @tennisgent I edited the question and added some code samples.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try and see whether the Audio API works for you (which existed before the HTML5 `<audio>`). It can directly read `ArrayBuffer`s

For example, loading a **WAV** is simple:

HTML:

```
<input id="files" type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Javscript:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new window.AudioContext();
var source;
function playSound(arraybuffer) {
    context.decodeAudioData(arraybuffer, function (buf) {
        source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.buffer = buf;
        source.start(0);
    });
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    playFile(files[0]);
}

function playFile(file) {
    var freader = new FileReader();

    freader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        playSound(e.target.result);
    };
    freader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/8xZUD/2/

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/13471195250/web-audio-api-how-to-playing-audio-based-on-user

Comment: Thank you but this does not seem to be working in Chrome for Android either. I have tried on two different devices with different versions of Android - one of them 4.0.4 and the other 4.1.1.

Comment: the jsfiddle does work in chrome on android 6.0 for me.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input id="file" type="File" name="fileupload">
<button onclick="upload()" type="submit">Upload</button>
<div id="song"></div>
```

**JS:**

```js
const upload = () => {
  var url;
  var file = document.querySelector("#file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    url = evt.target.result;
    console.log(url);
    var sound = document.createElement("audio");
    var link = document.createElement("source");
    sound.id = "audio-player";
    sound.controls = "controls";
    link.src = url;
    sound.type = "audio/mpeg";
    sound.appendChild(link);
    document.getElementById("song").appendChild(sound);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

```html
<input id="file" type="File" name="fileupload">
 <button onclick="upload()" type="submit">Upload</button>
 <div id="song"></div>
```

```
 const upload = () => {
  var url;
  var file = document.querySelector("#file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    url = evt.target.result;
    console.log(url);
    var sound = document.createElement("audio");
    var link = document.createElement("source");
    sound.id = "audio-player";
    sound.controls = "controls";
    link.src = url;
    sound.type = "audio/mpeg";
    sound.appendChild(link);
    document.getElementById("song").appendChild(sound);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```